# How to generate source file with some preprocessor #define applied

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I have some C/C++ source file (.hpp,.cpp) containing something like

```cpp
...
   #define SOME_DEFINE(t)  some_ns::some_type<t>
...

// define is somehow used later in the code
```

I would like to have a modified source (for readability) to have all the `SOME_DEFINE(t)` to be substituted in this file.

So I'm definitely not willing to apply a preprocessor compiler step - only this `#define` substituted and only for this source file.

Comment: I do not know how complex the actual example is but you might get away with `sed` and basic regexs.

Comment: @halt9k Not sure if unifdef can do what I like. I will take another look, but I was under impression that unifdef removes #ifdef. What I think I want is a tool, that have an imaginary interface like `tool <source_file> SOME_DEFINE`. So it goes through `source_file` and does substitution with whatever is there in `#define` line.

Comment: @Quimby a sed and regex is ok, I guess, but maybe some ready-made tool exists

Comment: @psb I am not aware of any unfortunately.

Comment: how about using a template alias `template <typename T> SOME_DEFINE = some_ns::some_type<T>;` then you only need to replace `SOME_DEFINE(t)` with `SOME_DEFINE<t>`, should be doable with a simple regex

Comment: @psb Excuse me about  unifdef, if does (and I used it) almost for what you ask, but only for ifdefs. Thought it can work on any macro too. Comment above is excessive.

Comment: *"with some preprocessor #define applied"* -- you mean with **one** preprocessor #define applied? After reading your question several times, I think that's what you mean. You have a source file that you want to process with a single macro substitution, even if there are other preprocessor directives in the file, right? Could you make this clearer in your question title and body?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options..

- Run the preprocessor and store the output. With gcc it is `-E` to get the output after preprocessor. Depedning on how much other preprocessing is used in the sources, this might be viable or not.
- Use a regex to search and replace.
- Use a template alias `template <typename T> SOME_DEFINE = some_ns::some_type<T>;` . Then use search and replace via regex to replace `SOME_DEFINE(t)` with `SOME_DEFINE<T>`.
- Find a tool that does it out of the box. Actually I am not aware of one, though tool recomenadations are offtopic anyhow. In a comment https://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/ was metioned.